# What is the meaining of '#' symbol in function name?

Tags: vimscript

I would like to know what is the meaning of the `#` symbol in function names e.g.:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
```

Comment: Read the help related to autoload plugins.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's part of the autoload
 mechanism. From
[`Autoloading`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/53.html) at 
[Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) 
and [`:help autoload`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#autoload):

Autoload lets you delay loading code until it's actually needed, so if the 
following function

```
execute pathogen#infect()
```

has already been loaded, Vim will simply call it normally.  Otherwise Vim will
look for a file called `autoload/pathogen.vim` in your `~/.vim` directory . If this
file exists, Vim will load/source the file. It will then try to call the
function normally.

Every `#` in the function name works like a path separator.  Thus when calling a
function:

```
:call foo#bar#func()
```

Vim will look for the file `autoload/foo/bar.vim`